# Help with Prompting for and Storing Information

Tags: c

The code below is `supposed` to prompt the user, step-by-step, for information. Currently, however, it waits for information and *then* display the prompts as well as the provided content. Can anyone explain why this is happening? Thanks.

*contacts.h* file

```
struct contacts {
    int phone_number;
    char first_name[11], last_name[11];
};
```

*rolodex.c* file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "contacts.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    struct contacts* c = (struct contacts*) malloc(sizeof(struct contacts));
    if (c == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    set_first_name(c);
    set_last_name(c);
    set_phone_number(c);
    display_contact(c);
}

int set_first_name(struct contacts* c) {
    puts("\nWhat is your first name? ");
    gets(c->first_name);
    return 0;
}

int set_last_name(struct contacts* c) {
    puts("\nWhat is your last name? ");
    gets(c->last_name);
    return 0;
}

int set_phone_number(struct contacts* c) {
    printf("\nWhat is your phone number? ");
    scanf(" %d", &c->phone_number);
    return 0;
}

int display_contact(struct contacts* c) {
    printf("\nName: %s %s Number: %d", c->first_name, c->last_name, c->phone_number);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `gets()`. It is unsafe and it is impossible to make it safe. Use `fgets()` instead: `fgets(c->last_mame, sizeof c->last_name, stdin);`

Comment: +1 for a properly asked question with the relevant code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard output stream is line buffered by default. That means that output shorter than a whole line is not guaranteed to be seen before execution continues with other statements.

Either end your output with a `'\n'` or `fflush(stdout)`.

Example
*EDITED: the previous example used `puts` which already ends the output with a `'\n'`*

```
int set_phone_number(struct contacts* c) {
    printf("\nWhat is your phone number?\n"); /* \n at end of output */
    scanf(" %d", &c->phone_number);
    return 0;
}
```

or

```
int set_phone_number(struct contacts* c) {
    printf("\nWhat is your phone number? ");
    fflush(stdout);                           /* force output */
    scanf(" %d", &c->phone_number);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up about `gets` and the explanation that the std output stream is line buffered. I tried both of the methods you suggested above (terminating a line with `\n` and flushing output) and only the latter method worked. Any idea why?

Comment: Both should work. I don't know why `fflush(stdout)` works and terminating `printf()` with a `'\n'` doesn't. What is your hardware, OS, compiler, compilation options? Maybe on your system, `stdout` is fully buffered by default (which, I think, is illegal by the Standard) ...

Comment: I'm using `msys (mingw32)` on vista with `gcc` and the compilation cmd is: `gcc -o rolodex rolodex.c`.

Comment: @DanMark: I don't know if [issue 56 of mintty](http://code.google.com/p/mintty/issues/detail?id=56) is relevant. If it is, you're doomed to using `fflush(stdout);` (or even uglier workarounds): "difficulty: insane" :)

Answer (score 0):

Windows doesn't support line buffeting. By default, streams are unbuffered in the console window and on serial lines, and fully buffered elsewhere. As an alternative to flushing manually, buffering can be disabled with setvbuf().